# Get every 3rd item from 2D NumPy array with a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a NumPy array with size (4061, 3). I need to iterate through it using a for loop so that I can segment it into 4061 (1,3) arrays which will be assigned to a list as the for loop executes.

Comment: You could probably do this with a secondary variable that resets every third run and adds items to a list. What have you tried so far to solve this issue?

Comment: `for row in my_array: print(row)`, but why?

Comment: @QuangHoang I'm trying to append it to a list. Do you know how I could add each of the three values as seperate entries in a list for the length of the array (4061)?

Answer (score 0):

A possible answer could be:

```
my_list= []
count= 0
my_array= np.eye(4061, 3) # here define your (4061,3) array
for i in my_array:
    count=count+1
    if (count%3)==0 :
        my_list.append(i)
```